# Sync two database tables SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

We have two databases, one at our client's site and another (Main) in our data centre.

Both databases have the same schema, we want to sync the databases periodically (twice a day) so that both should have the same data.

We are you using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Please suggest a good methodology.

The number of rows modified is approx to 400 rows a day

Comment: Look into Merge Replication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Job that selects from the client's database tables and inserts in your database tables.

If both the databases are in different servers you can create a linked server at your server and connect it to the client server.

Then you can schedule the job to run whenever you want.

Comment: Could you please provide me a link from where i can start

Comment: You can try these links http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35943/How-to-Config-Linked-Servers-in-a-Minute
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx
Also if you google Linked server you will find other helpful stuff. 
Good luck

Comment: Also the Comment on your post about Merge Replication is something you should really consider because it is much faster than normal inserting. But anyway you have to use it in the job through the linked server